# What is This Strange Ternary-Looking Operation?

Tags: javascript, syntax, flowtype

I've been reading through the Flux library source code, and in a few places I see this notation:

```
?: ?
```

I'm not sure if this is a strange use of the ternary operator, or something else entirely.

Several good examples of confusing usage of this can be found in the function declaration starting on [line 245 of the FluxContainer.js](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/container/FluxContainer.js) file:

```
function createFunctional<Props, State, A, B>(
    viewFn: (props: State) => React.Element<State>,
    getStores: (props?: ?Props, context?: any) => Array<FluxStore>,
    calculateState: (prevState?: ?State, props?: ?Props, context?: any) => State,
    options?: Options,
): ReactClass<Props> {
    /** Omitted Implementation Details **/
};
```

What is happening here, such as in `props?: ?Props`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a [flow](https://flow.org/en/) type notation.

The `param?: ?Type` notation means that `param` is an [optional parameter](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-optional-parameters) and that `Type` is a [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/). It basically accepts the `Type` plus `undefined` and `null`.